# Detect duplicate values from properties in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, interface

Is there a way to detect duplicate values from properties in a TypeScript interface? ex:

```
interface Props {
   foo: string;
   bar: string;
}

let x : Props = {
   foo: 'hello world',
   bar: 'hello world'
} 

// show TypeScript warning for foo and bar having the same value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concrete type in TypeScript that represents such a constraint.  Instead, you could use a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types) and a helper function to produce values of that type.  Like, for example, this:

```
const asDistinctProps = <F extends string, B extends string>(
    props: { foo: F, bar: Exclude<B, F> }
) => props;
```

Here, `asDistinctProps` is a generic function that takes an object with `string`-valued `foo` and `bar` properties.  But the type of `bar` is constrained so that it cannot be the same value as the `foo` type... as long as you're dealing with [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) and not just `string`:

```
let x = asDistinctProps({
    foo: 'hello world',
    bar: 'hello world' // error!
});

let y = asDistinctProps({
    foo: 'hello world',
    bar: 'goodbye cruel world'
}); // okay
```

So that works the way you want.

---

Do remember though that the compiler will often widen a string from its literal value to `string`, and at that point it's not possible to properly apply the constraint.  Here:

```
let z: string = "hello";
asDistinctProps({foo: z, bar: "goodbye"}); // error!
```

you are prevented from using `asDistinctProps` at all because the `foo` property is just `string`.  And here:

```
asDistinctProps({ foo: "hello", bar: z }); // no error!
```

you are not prevented from specifying the same value twice because the compiler does not see `string` as conflicting with `"hello"`.

---

So with the above caveats, it's sort of possible.  In practice I'd probably make the constraint enforced primarily at runtime and not worry about having the type system involved too much.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAIgS2sswoAUBOIAOEMAvDADwBiMApgB5TVgAmR0O6A5gDQwBCN9RixhtOAPgAUAKBiyY+PIQBcMAN4wAZiBAqKPAEZwcKgKK1gAGwCuTamV48KYmAF8pAShLOFBCAG4pKQtqWFoSeCRUKHRMXF8JVRk5LR0YAHIAC2oLCxAYAHcQHAsmNK4k2UNjdKycvMLi0pgAemaaHDwcAEIpF3cAoJCYAE9whBQ0DGxFCASKzW0VTOzcgqKSsvmqpY5tJn1h6hhgHCtstca03v6WtpAAazhhmUHYAC8VUTAOcIAiWtyvwC4yiMWm8XUKRUbwMRhUv12IH2h1+rhurXanS6MECIMmsRmCQWqX+KxAv1h1TeaL8txgYDy1A6RS6QA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer @jcalz!